# How does the Linux file structure work?

Tags: linux, filesystems, files, directory, directory-structure

I see the different folders `bin`, `dev`, `mnt`, `proc`, `srv`, `sys`, etc.

What are the properties of all these different folders? What are their purposes? Are there files in some of them that I should not touch? Should I be touching files in the other folders?

Final question: in a Unix environment, do folders == directories? I apologize for all the questions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filesystem Hierarchy Standard: http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml

GNU coding standards: http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/ also has policies on directory usage, and sometimes disagrees with FHS

"Folder" is a term used by Mac and Windows people to refer to directories. Using it in unix land makes you sound like a newbie who hasn't gotten oriented yet.

Comment: This clears up a lot.